# Uncaught Error: No context provided: useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of <MapContainer>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using react-leaflet and I added a marker with an event Handler on click to zoom to this marker , but when I try to use const map=useMap() all I get is this error => :

```
Uncaught Error: No context provided: useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of <MapContainer>
```

There might be similar questions but none have answers, can anyone please help with this?
This is my code:

```
const map = useMap()
 return (
        <div>
          <MapContainer
            className="leaflet-container"
            center={[33.8735578, 35.86379]}
            zoom={9}>

            <TileLayer
              attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />

            <Marker
              icon={port}
              eventHandlers={{
                click: (e) => {
                  map.setView(e.latlng, 14);
                },
              }}
              position={[33.90757548098519, 35.51700873340635]}
            ></Marker>
          </MapContainer>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

well I solved it by making a separate component for the marker and implement the useMap() in it and it worked as so :

```
import React from "react";
import { Marker, useMap } from "react-leaflet";

export default function Markerwhatever(props) {
  const map = useMap();

  return (
    <div>
      <Marker
        icon={props.icon}
        position={[33.91907336973602, 35.51552625946782]}
        eventHandlers={{
          click: (e) => {
            map.flyTo(e.latlng, 14);
          },
        }}
      ></Marker>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: could u give  more info on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you got the issue

```
No context provided: useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of <MapContainer>
```

after upgrading react-leaflet and/or leaflet, you should **remove and re-add the plugin package** (in my case the marker cluster plugin) because the upgrade may have create conflict in the packages versions.

Answer (score 0):

If useMap is not imported from react-leaflet, then you are using older verions. v2
you need to run `npm i @react-leaflet/core`
if issue still persist
remove node_modules and clear cache `npm cache clear --force`
and install npm i

Comment: I am having the same issue, and this didn`t help...

Comment: Please check leaflet version and react-leaflet version.
note: react >=18 doesnot supports less than leaflet v3